# For-expression throws NullPointerException on collection declared in Companion object

Tags: scala

I have the following code (simplified):

```
case class Element(x : Int, y : Int)

case class Controller(elems: Set[Element]) {
  import Controller._

  def neighbours(e : Element) : Set[Element] = Set.empty[Element] // this is only to get the code to compile
  def merge(that : Controller) : Controller = Controller(elems ++ that.elems)

  def evolve : Controller = {
    {
      println(s"Evolving using rules $rules");
      for(rule <- rules) yield {
        println(s"Handling rule $rule")
        Controller(for(c <- elems; if !rule(c,neighbours(c))) yield c)
      }
    }.foldLeft(empty)(_.merge(_))
  }
}

object Controller{
  type Rule = (Element, Set[Element]) => Boolean
  val empty = Controller(Set.empty[Element])

  val rules : Set[Rule] = Set(rule1,rule2)
  val rule1 : Rule = (e : Element, set : Set[Element]) => set.size < 2
  val rule2 : Rule = (e : Element, set : Set[Element]) => set.size < 4 && set.size > 1
}
```

My problem is that the `evolve` method thrown a NullPointer exception.
After some investigation, I realized that the problem is with the `rules` set in the companion object that, for some reason, is Set(null) at the moment is used as shown in the println at `println(s"Evolving using rules $rules");`.

Can anybody explain why is that?
Why is rules Set(null), if I add two `rule`s to it that I anonymously implement in the following lines?
Does the issue have anything to do with the fact that I have a case class and that the Companion object is not working as I expect it to work?

Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** It's initialization order.

Your code could be shortened to

```
object Foo { 
    val foo = Set(bar1, bar2)
    val bar1 = "a"
    val bar2 = "b"
}
```

The problem is that declarations are processed in top-down manner, so at the time when foo is initialized and value is set, bar1 and bar2 are not yet assigned, so the call looks like

```
val foo = Set(null, null)
```

which result in Set(null) obviously.

To solve this problem, move rule1 and rule2 before rules (alternatively, swap `val` with `def` or apply `lazy val` for rule1/rule2, but I doubt this is the case for you).

You may argue that in java you would not have the same problem, but you will -- the almost exact translation would be:

```
class Foo {
    Set<String> foo;
    String bar1;
    String bar2;

    Foo() {
        foo = new HashSet<String>();
        foo.add(bar1);
        foo.add(bar2);
        bar1 = "a";
        bar2 = "b";
    }
}
```